# Optimizing Conduit pipelines

Tags: haskell, optimization, conduit

I'm currently benchmarking my program to see whether I can improve its performance. Currently my program will take an input file and run some algorithm to split it into multiple files.

It takes roughly 14s to split a file into 3 parts, with `-O2` compilation flag for both library and executable.

```
ghc-options:         -Wall -fno-warn-orphans -O2 -auto-all
```

It looks like it is spending approximately 60% of its time in `sinkFile`, and I'm wondering whether there is anything I can do to improve the following code.

```
-- | Get the sink file, a list of FilePaths and the share number of the file to output to.
idxSinkFile :: MonadResource m
            => [FilePath]
            -> Int
            -> Consumer [Word8] m ()
idxSinkFile outFileNames shareNumber =
    let ccm = CC.concatMap $ flip atMay shareNumber 
        cbs = CC.map BS.singleton 
        sf = sinkFile (outFileNames !! shareNumber)
    in ccm =$= cbs =$= sf

-- | Generate a sink which will take a list of bytes and write each byte to its corresponding file share
sinkMultiFiles :: MonadResource m
               => [FilePath]
               -> [Int]
               -> Sink [Word8] m ()
sinkMultiFiles outFileNames xs =
    let len = [0..length xs - 1]
    in getZipSink $ otraverse_ (ZipSink . idxSinkFile outFileNames) len
```

Here are the output of GHC's profiling:

```
                                                                                                   individual     inherited
COST CENTRE                              MODULE                                 no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

     splitFile.sink                      HaskSplit.Conduit.Split                289           1    0.0    0.0    66.8   74.2
      sinkMultiFiles                     HaskSplit.Conduit.Split                290           1   27.4   33.2    66.8   74.2
       idxSinkFile                       HaskSplit.Conduit.Split                303           3    7.9   11.3    39.4   41.0
        idxSinkFile.ccm                  HaskSplit.Conduit.Split                319           3    3.1    3.6     3.1    3.6
        idxSinkFile.cbs                  HaskSplit.Conduit.Split                317           3    3.5    4.2     3.5    4.2
        idxSinkFile.sf                   HaskSplit.Conduit.Split                307           3   24.9   21.9    24.9   21.9
       sinkMultiFiles.len                HaskSplit.Conduit.Split                291           1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
```

Which shows `sinkFile` taking a lot of time. (I've benchmarked the list access etc in case you're wondering and they have 0% of processing)

While I understand for a small program like this IO is often the bottleneck, I'd like to see if I can improve the runtime performance of my program.

Cheers!

Comment: It would probably be more informative to recompile `conduit` and `conduit-extra` with `-auto-all` as well and see in more detail where time is being spent.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman, Hmm I was more hoping that it's something I'm not doing right. I'll try dig deeper. Do you have a rough example of the speed of `sinkFile`, from any past experience?

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant to your program but some webservers like way/warp use blaze-builder to build ByteStrings that can be output efficiently

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems to me that by using `BS.singleton`, you create an enormous amount of `ByteStrings` (one per `Word8`) sprayed around in memory, losing any compactness/memory locality benefits that packed strings give you, and also allocating a `ByteString` header (`PS (ForeignPtr Word8) Int Int` - that's even bigger than a list node) *per char*. In addition, `sinkFile` is eventually implemented with `awaitForever $ liftIO . BS.hPut h`, so you have one `await` loop per character instead of writing packed chunks to the file.

Comment: Cheers guys, that's some really good points. I'll look into it.

Comment: @nh2, I've posted my attempt at your suggestion. Does that look ok to you? If so, would you please put your comment as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Following nh2's advice, I decided to pack the `ByteStrings` in 256 byte chunks instead of doing a `BS.singleton` on each `Word8` instance.

```
cbs = CL.sequence (CL.take 256) =$= CC.map BS.pack
```

instead of

```
cbs = CC.map BS.singleton
```

and I'm able to reduce the running time as well as the memory usage quite significantly, as demonstrated below:

**Original Run**

```
total time  =      194.37 secs   (194367 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
total alloc = 102,021,859,892 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)
```

**New Run, with `CL.take`**

```
total time  =       35.88 secs   (35879 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
total alloc = 21,970,152,800 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)
```

That's some serious improvement! I'd like to optimize it more but that's for another question :)